# Что нужно сделать, то бы при апдейте записи в sql который содержит путь к картинке, не пропадали бэкслэши?

Tags: java, netbeans

Этим же кодом я добавляю(`INSERT`) запись и путь остается с бэкслешами. Прим.: `C:\Users\COMP\Desktop\Kartinka.png`, когда же, к примеру, хочу изменить(`UPDATE`) этот путь через этот же код, оно мне заменяет, но убирает бэкслэши. Прим.: `C:UsersCOMPDesktopKartinka.png`

В чем проблема, и как это исправить?

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
jTextField1.setText(filename);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Запрос на обновление записи:

```
query = "UPDATE battle SET name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', Image = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' WHERE name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"' ;";
```

Comment: Приведите код добавления/обновления данных в БД.

Comment: `query = "UPDATE battle SET name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"', Image = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' WHERE name = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"' ;";`

Comment: На добавление я делал немного по другому, но сделав так же и для обновления, суть не поменялась.
`protected void insertW(String s1, String s2)
query = "INSERT INTO db.work (db.work .name, db.work .Image) VALUES (?,?);";` и через insertW передаю значение с поля,  `insertW(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText());`

Comment: Используйте тот способ и при update. `query = "UPDATE battle SET name = ?, Image = ? WHERE name = ? ;";`

Answer (score 1):

Экранируйте символ `\`, то есть замените его на `\\`. Тогда путь будет следующим `C:\\Users\\COMP\\Desktop\\Kartinka.png`. А еще лучше замените на `/`, так как они универсальны и поддерживаются в Windows.

Примечание: используйте placeholder `?` при обновлении данных.

```
query = "UPDATE battle SET name = ?, Image = ? WHERE name = ? ;";
```